# metodo de busqueda

Tags: java

```
//crear una estructura de datos que lea los libros de una biblioteca 
//y logremos obtener el nombre del autor del libro y la naturalidad
package libro;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Libro {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        proceso l;
        l = new proceso();

        int i=0,n;
        System.out.println("Cuántos libros desea ingresar:");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        while(i<n){
        l.libros();
        l.nombreA();
        l.naturalidad();
        i=i+1;
        }
    }

}


package libro;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class proceso{

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     String libros[],naturalidad[],nombreA[];
     int i=0;
     public void libros()
     {  
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del libro:");
        libros[i]=sc.nextLine();
     }

     public void nombreA()
     {
         System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del autor:");
         nombreA[i]=sc.nextLine();
     }

     public void naturalidad ()
     {
         System.out.println("Ingrese la naturalidad del libro:");
         naturalidad[i]=sc.nextLine();
     }

     public static String BusquedaSecuencial(){
         String elem;
            for (int i = 0; i < libros.length; ++i)
            {
                if (vector[i] == elem)
                {
                    return i;
                    return -1;
                }
            }
     }

}
```

Este es mi ejercicio pero no se como implementar el método de búsqueda. Necesito saber el autor y la naturalidad de un libro solo cuando el usuario ingrese su nombre.

Muchas gracias si alguien me puede ayudar le agradecería

Comment: Y qué error te da, o en qué parte falla? sin detalles es difícil proporcionar ayuda

Comment: @Sr1871 todo el metodo de busqueda esta malo, lo mande solo para que vieran mi intento pero nose como crearlo

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo una forma de hacer tu búsqueda seria la siguiente:

```
 public static String BusquedaSecuencial(String nombre){

            for (int i = 0; i < libros.length; ++i)
            {
                if (libros[i] == nombre)
                {
                    return "Autor: " nombreA[i]+" "+"Naturalidad: "+ 
                    naturalidad[i];
                }
            }
     }
```

Esto en el supuesto de que insertes el los datos en los arreglos en la misma posición para todos.

Y en tu main solo mandas a traer la función y muestras el resultado.

```
System.out.println (BusquedaSecuencial("NOMBRE DEL LIBRO"));
```